# Repo problem in build farm after moving package out of metapackage

Tags: ros, bloom-release, rosdistro, metapackage, buildfarm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**tl;dr:** Due to bad planning, I bloom-released a metapkg and now I want to get one of the pkgs out to become an independent pkg. Already updated rosdistro/indigo/distribution.yaml and forced farm rebuilds a couple times. Build farms still tries to clone OLD_REPO-release instead of NEW_REPO-release. **What else should I try?**

**Details:**

1. Metapackage is `mrpt_navigation`. See [rosdistro entry](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/indigo/distribution.yaml#L3383)
2. Yesterday it contained a package named `pose_cov_ops`, I had to manually remove it because otherwise bloom complained (correctly) when trying to release the new package because it was already in the metapkg. See [commit](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/commit/39ce987dafe0534a9d790f00ea8e065d2f48622f).
3. After that, I manually finished the PR that bloom failed to do. See [commit](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/commit/bd8bd6d83009f4c8b95ed2abab5b87e1570894c6)
4. bloom succeeds in subsequent releases. See [commit](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/commit/43cca4f25f3fb31db793262cf6932cf839d8912a).
5. This is the current entry of the new pkg In rosdistro:

   pose_cov_ops:
   doc:
   type: git
   url: https://github.com/mrpt-ros-pkg/pose_cov_ops.git
   version: master
   release:
   tags:
   release: release/indigo/{package}/{version}
   url: https://github.com/mrpt-ros-pkg-release/pose_cov_ops-release.git       ## <<<< NEW, CORRECT REPO URI (this comment is not on rosdistro!!)
   version: 0.1.5-0
   source:
   type: git
   url: https://github.com/mrpt-ros-pkg/pose_cov_ops.git
   version: master
   status: maintained
6. But the build farm still believes the **release repository is the OLD one** (see [complete log](http://jenkins.ros.org/job/ros-indigo-pose-cov-ops_sourcedeb/13/console)):

   - cd /home/rosbuild/hudson/workspace/ros-indigo-pose-cov-ops_sourcedeb/workspace && gbp-clone https://github.com/mrpt-ros-pkg-release/mrpt_navigation-release.git
     Fetching targets
   - cd /home/rosbuild/hudson/workspace/ros-indigo-pose-cov-ops_sourcedeb/workspace/mrpt_navigation-release && git tag -l debian/*
     No matching tag found. Are you sure you pointed to the right repository or the version is right?, expected debian/ros-indigo-pose-cov-ops_0.1.5-0_saucy:

Notice it uses the OLD repo URI: https://github.com/mrpt-ros-pkg-release/mrpt_navigation-release.git instead of the one provided in rosdistro... Why?

I tried to trace where the incorrect repository URI comes from and found it to come from:

- the input argument "repo_uri" of ros-infrastructure/buildfarm/scripts/generate_sourcedeb
- which comes from RELEASE_URI in source_build.sh
- from "doit(release_uri,..." in  release_jobs.py

But: WHO calls release_jobs.py? I couldn't find it.

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199996/repo-problem-in-build-farm-after-moving-package-out-of-metapackage/) by [Jose Luis Blanco](https://answers.ros.org/users/2046/jose-luis-blanco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 288 on 2014-12-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Jenkins jobs are only regenerated once every 24h. Please wait at least until tomorrow - the job should be updated by then. If the problem persists please comment here again.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jose Luis Blanco](https://answers.ros.org/users/2046/jose-luis-blanco/) on 2014-12-24**:
As usual, you're right... Without further changes it now builds. Thanks!